# node.js docker image for all environments - including production

Tags: node.js, docker, production, environments

Currently we are using node:4.2.3 (LTS) docker image which is around 642 MB in size and node_modules around 140 MB in total ~800MB to build our web application docker image.

Publishing these images to our private registry and pulling them all environments becoming a time taken process.

Since we cant reduce the node_modules size( would be helpful if any reducing methods are avail) looking for suggestions to use any other node docker image for all environments - including production.

Answer (score 1):

You can build your own docker images using following **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y wget

# install node v4.2.6
RUN wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v4.2.6/node-v4.2.6-linux-x64.tar.gz && \
    tar -C /usr/local --strip-components 1 -xzf node-v4.2.6-linux-x64.tar.gz && \
    rm node-v4.2.6-linux-x64.tar.gz 

# install express 4.13.4
RUN npm install express@4.13.4
```

Using following command to build the image:

```
sudo docker build -t ubuntu-node .
```

The image is only **255MB**

```
REPOSITORY               TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
ubuntu-node              latest              7ed1b88adb46        7 seconds ago       255 MB
```

Of course, you can install any necessary dependencies.

Comment: 255 MB is affordable, can we reduce it to further - rather than taking it "FROM ubuntu:14.04" any other linux dis which is very small (20 -40 MB) and install node on top of it. 
Any comments on [alpinelinux](http://www.alpinelinux.org) and [alpine-node](https://hub.docker.com/r/mhart/alpine-node/)

Comment: I'm not familiar with alpinelinux or apline-node. In my opinion, using familiar OS base images is much more better since we may need to install other dependencies. In addition, image size is not a major problem when you use docker.

Comment: We have successfully used alpine linux and delivered it to client, ofcourse there are some security vulnerabilities available in base image of alpine linux, which we now identified using Docker Trusted Registry.